# setBackground android ImageButton function doesn't update color if it's not called twice

Tags: android, repaint, android-imagebutton

I have an Android tablet with two profiles. One is Administrator profile and another one is a limited guest profile. The code I am developing must change the color of an Android ImageButton from a listener. The function that updates the ImageButton color is called as follows:

```
private static void udate_color() {
    UIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageButton image_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.messageButton);
            image_button.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_border_grey_curved));
    });
}
```

If the tablet is in Administrator profile the color is updated without any problem. If the tablet is in the limited guest profile the above code doesn't work; the color is only updated if the function setBackground color is called two times. If the function is only called one time the color is not updated. That means that for the limited guest profile the code that works as the previous example is as follows:

```
private static void udate_color() {
    UIHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ImageButton image_button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.messageButton);
            image_button.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_border_grey_curved));
            image_button.setBackground(res.getDrawable(R.drawable.green_border_grey_curved));
    });
}
```

I have not found any issue with ImageButton repainting and android user profiles. Does anybody know how is the correct way of solving this issue and why is this happening?

Comment: Are you sure that both of your function are not called on the "same" time?

Comment: What do you mean? I realized that calling the function two times changes the color because if the listener that calls update_color() is executed two times the color is changed. That's why I "solved" the issue calling two times setBackground function.

Comment: I mean you have to implementation of udate_color, are you sure that both are not called?

Comment: I have implemented update_color function and it is called everytime the listener is executed. I still don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, the problem was with the xml layout file; in this file I had defined an initial color value. Removing this part from the xml file and setting programatically the color has solved the problem.